# Is it possible to send Variable or parameter in log4j Socket Appender?

Tags: java, log4j

Along with the logs generated, I want to send some variable or parameter through SocketAppender.

I have a code Step (which I don't know how it works!) in which an ID is generated by some other java file in some other package, according to which logs filename are generated.

For ex- If id generated is 10111, then log file name will be log10111.log

Now, I want to send this ID so that in the host where server is running, Log are generated according to ID.

Is that possible?